# Enable mysqli on Linux AMI EC2 Instance for phpMyAdmin 5.0.2 install

Tags: php, linux, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I am trying to enable the mysqli php extension on my Linux AMI EC2 Instance so I can access phpMyAdmin 5.0.2. The current version of php that was installed is 7.2. When I go to access try to access phpMyAdmin console, it says it is missing the mysqli extension. I ran the following command to check to see if it is enabled and it just comes out blank:

`php -m | grep mysqli`

So, I successfully installed mysqli by running:

`sudo su yum install yum install php72-mysqli -y`

I then successfully restarted the Apache server using the following command:

`sudo su service httpd restart`

I then ran the `php -m | grep mysqli` to see if mysqli was enabled and the command does not produce anything showing it is enabled.

Can anyone help me enable the mysqli php extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to enable mysqli by restarting the mysqld daemon by inputting:

`sudo su service mysqld restart`

The phpMyAdmin page came up properly.